# Passing The Right Series Of Arguments

Tags: javascript

In one HTML page, I have 2 onclick events like this :

```
onclick="clear_input('button1', 'hello1','world1');"
onclick="clear_input('button2','hello2','world2');"
```

In a JS file I have this :

```
function clear_input(a, b, c) {

var text = document.getElementById(b);

var button = document.getElementById(a);

…

}
```

It all works. Now I want to get rid of the inline JS and implement in the JS file an addEventListener that could process any one of the 2 onclick events. How do I pass the right series of arguments ?

Comment: What elements are you onclicks set on? Your elements may have to store the arguments (using data-* attributes?) to know which args are tied to which element.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just two, it's probably not worth effort to create some generic solution.  Just add each call individually.

```
document.getElementById('whatever1').addEventListener('click', function(){
    clear_input('button1', 'hello1', 'world1');
});
document.getElementById('whatever2').addEventListener('click', function(){
    clear_input('button2', 'hello2', 'world2');
});
```

If you need a more generic solution you'll need to explain more about the situation, like why the arguments are 'button1', 'hello1', 'world1' to start with.